Как удалить убрать всплывающую картинку с браузерами
Как удалить убрать всплывающую картинку с браузерами в Android Studio?
Какая-то лишняя опция, когда что-либо редактируешь это всплывающее окно с браузерами очень мешает - мне это не нужно.


Откройте настройки. Далее, для простоты, введите в строке поиска: web browsers and preview
Далее найдите секцию Show browser popup in the editor и уберите галочку с пункта For XML files. Либо везде снимите галочки.

